# awk a variable as a regex

Tags: awk, regular-expression, variable

The question is really simple, I have read all the questions and still cannot make it! I have a plain file like this

```
$cat file1.txt
ALA
AJD
KSF
```

And I want awk to use each of the values as regex to print lines from another file to another one:

```
$cat file2.txt
name,st,ed,le
ALA,10,12,12
ALA,2,5,4
ALA,6,5,8
AJD,5,8,7
KSF,5,8,7
```

So my script is

```
while read p;
awk -F"," 'NR==1{print $0}' file2.txt > $p.csv
awk -F"," '/$p/{print $0}' file2.txt >> $p.csv
done <file1.txt
```

And the desired output would be:

```
$cat ALA.csv
name,st,ed,le
ALA,10,12,12
ALA,2,5,4
ALA,6,5,8
$cat AJD.csv
name,st,ed,le
AJD,5,8,7
$cat KSF.csv
name,st,ed,le
KSF,5,8,7
```

Unfortunately, I only get the headers printed in each file.
I have manually put each value from file1.txt replacing $p and it works perfectly. So I think the problem is that the variable $p is not been well interpreted. I tried with quotes, double simple. I tried also many different suggestions I found, but nothing seems to work!

Answer (score 4):

While you could do:

```
awk "/$p/" file2.txt > "$p.csv"
```

That is have the shell *expand* the content of the `$p` shell variable in the code passed to `awk`, that's bad practice and basically amounts to a command injection vulnerability (for instance for a value of `$p` like `^/{system("reboot");/`). Best is to pass the shell variable as is to awk and use awk's `~` operator for regexp matching. The best way is via an environment variable and `awk`'s `ENVIRON` special array:

```
export P
while IFS= read -r P; do
  awk 'NR == 1 || $0 ~ ENVIRON["P"]' < file2.txt > "$P.csv"
done < file1.txt
```

But here, you could avoid the shell loop and do only one pass in the files:

```
awk 'NR == FNR {files[$0]; next}
     FNR == 1 {for (f in files) print > f ".csv"; next}
     {
       for (f in files)
         if ($0 ~ f) print > f ".csv"
     }' file1.txt file2.txt
```

Comment: Is there really a difference if the variable is passed through the environment or via `-vP="$P"`? Can the second one choke on some weird special character?

Comment: @ikkachu, yes `-vP="$P"` does some backslash sequence expansion (typically a problem with regexps that often contain backslashes). See https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A22565+ENVIRON+ARGV+awk

Comment: By the way `-vP="$P"` doesn't work in many _traditional_ implementations of `awk` where you need `-v P="$P"`.(`-v` and `P="$P"` being separate arguments).

Comment: Much memory save if you iterate through fields not through array `{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i in files)print > $i ".csv"` (do not forget `FS=OFS=","`)

Comment: @Costas, that would be functionally different. I'm not sure how that would save memory though. And you could write the same line several times into a given file.

Comment: May be it is expected behavior if there are different patterns in one line?